# Bit.Ly (Simple Integration)

Tags: php, forms, url-shortener

I was wondering if anyone could tell me the simplest way to implement the Bit.Ly URL shortening service into my website (using PHP). I have a form, that needs to work with the URL shortener, and if the shortened link could be saved as a variable? I've tried to follow the official documentation but I feel it's very blunt.

Answer (score 2):

here is a nice implementation:  http://davidwalsh.name/bitly-php